# Difference Between Safari Web Content and Safari Web Content (Cached)

Tags: safari, python

I created a program in Python to kill the `Safari Web Content (Cached)` processes. However, when I ran that program, I failed to take into account that Apple uses the same file for both version of `Safari Web Content`. The file, according to `ps -e` is `/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent`. How does Activity Monitor differentiate both `Safari Web Content`?

---

For those tech-savvy people, who want a challenge, here is my code.

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.run(['ps', '-e'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
output = output.split('\n')

for x in range(0, len(output)):
    output[x] = " ".join(output[x].split())
    if output[x].endswith("com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"):
        elemental_output = output[x].split(' ')
        pid = elemental_output[0]
        subprocess.run(["kill", pid], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: You should not kill that process, it works tighter with Safari main process and you may get a lot of troubles/unpredictable navigation errors, etc.. Why do you want to kill it? Is there a concrete reason for that? If yes, for sure there will be better ways to handle it.

Comment: @Prado To free up the enormous amount of RAM Safari uses to store cached files. Additionally, they're only cached files. They don't immediately do anything.

Comment: They do, they are files cached of your current opened Safari windows [files in actual use], extensions make use of it, also other plugins. The raw cache is stored on disk, but files which are in use are loaded on memory. I will look if there is a documented way for disabling it. I just am sure that if you keep killing it you will get trouble.

Comment: @Prado On your Mac open Activity Monitor. After browsing for a while in multiple tabs, close all the tabs except one. On Activity Monitor, there will be a number of processes called `Safari Web Content (Cached)`, however there are also some processes called `Safari Web Content`. I don't want to kill the `Safari Web Content` processes because I'm actually using those processes. I only want to kill the `Safari Web Content (Cached)` because those processes are from tabs that visited recently but have closed.

Comment: I did it, opened 6 safari windows, each of them with 5 tabs, then closed all except one windows [with 1 tab]. It remains on Activity monitor 7 process of Safari Web Content Cached running, and the sum of memory used by all of them all is 323MB. The bigger is 166MB, the smaller is 15Mb, average is about 30~50 MB each process

Comment: @Prado If I have a hight RAM application running (like IntelliJ) and I have many tabs open (for example SO), my Mac starts using Swap and comes to a halt.

Comment: I understood. I am trying to find a way to help you select just the cached one, if you want to do is OK, but both `ps` and `lsof` shows no difference about the label (between the cached and not-cached) as Activity monitor does.